# NIFI Insert CSV File into Postgres Database with date fields

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-nifi, avro

I would like to insert csv file into my postgres database. I use processors :

```
Getfiles -> 
Split (cause files are big) ->
UpdateAttribute (to add avro.schema) ->
ConvertCSvToAvro ->
Putdatabaserecord.
```

If i use only string/text fields (in my avro schema  and in column postgres database), the result is ok.
But when i tried to format Date fields, i have an error.

My raw data (CSV) is :

```
date_export|num_etiquette|key
07/11/2019 01:36:00|BAROMETRExxxxx|BAROMETRE-xxxxx
```

My avro schema is :

```
{
"type":"record",
"name":"public.data_scope_gp_temp",
"fields":[
{"name":"date_export","type":{ "type": "int", "logicalType": "date"}},
{"name":"num_etiquette","type":"string"},
{"name":"cle_scope","type":"string"}
]}
```

My postgres schema is:

```
date_export date,
num_etiquette text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
key text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
```

Any idea ?Regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't need UpdateAttribute or ConvertCsvToAvro to use PutDatabaseRecord. You can specify a CSVReader in PutDatabaseRecord, and your CSVReader can supply the Avro schema in the Schema Text property (don't forget to set your Schema Strategy to Use Schema Text).